# Syntax error: Unexpected T_String error in line 5 of the following code.

Tags: php

```
<?php

$db_name=“a7614252_booked”;
$mysql_user="a7614252_booked”;
$mysql_pass=“booked”;
$server_name="server38.000webhost.com”; //t_string error here. 

$con=mysqli_connect($server_name,$mysql_user,$mysql_pass,$db_name)or   die(‘Connection Error’.mysqli_connect_error());

?>
```

i have checked other responses on the same error but none of seem to be the answer to the problem here. Thank you.

Comment: Replace `“` with `"` and `‘` with `'`

Answer (score 0):

use this code, Replace `“` with `"` or `'`

```
<?php

$db_name="a7614252_booked";
$mysql_user="a7614252_booked";
$mysql_pass="booked";
$server_name="server38.000webhost.com"; //t_string error here. 

$con=mysqli_connect($server_name,$mysql_user,$mysql_pass,$db_name)or   die(‘Connection Error’.mysqli_connect_error());

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace all occurences of `“` with `"` AND also the backticks 
`` ` `` by `'`. Otherwise PHP will interprete the latter as bash commands.

```
$db_name="a7614252_booked";
$mysql_user="a7614252_booked";
$mysql_pass="booked";
$server_name="server38.000webhost.com"; //t_string error here. 
$con=mysqli_connect($server_name,$mysql_user,$mysql_pass,$db_name)or   die('Connection Error'.mysqli_connect_error());
```